# How to replace some rows of a dataset from another dataset in R

Tags: r, replace, dataset

I have two datasets. One the original called `geoIncendios` and a second called `outliers`. As you can imagine the latter is a subset consisting of the outliers of the former. After analyzing them, I found the error and corrected them. So now I would like to replace the rows of the first dataset with the second.

Here is the structure of both datasets to give you an idea:

```
> str(geoIncendios)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ id           : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ municipio    : chr  "LLANES" "CANIZA" "CANGAS DEL NARCEA" "PILONA" ...
 $ num_incendios: num  1725 1521 1349 1341 1290 ...
 $ ha_quemadas  : num  79 70 34 81 96 56 4 87 18 69 ...
 $ ranking      : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ comunidad    : chr  "ASTURIAS" "GALICIA" "ASTURIAS" "ASTURIAS" ...
 $ provincia    : chr  "ASTURIAS" "PONTEVEDRA" "ASTURIAS" "ASTURIAS" ...
 $ lon          : num  -4.76 -8.27 -6.55 -5.35 -7.11 ...
 $ lat          : num  43.4 42.2 43.2 43.3 42.2 ...

> str(outliers)
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ id           : num  9 13 22 24 37 40 43 45 68 93 ...
 $ municipio    : chr  "NEVES" "LENA" "TOMINO" "GRADO" ...
 $ num_incendios: num  1081 929 818 744 641 ...
 $ ha_quemadas  : num  18 74 73 49 61 48 38 21 46 8 ...
 $ ranking      : num  9 13 22 24 37 40 43 45 68 93 ...
 $ comunidad    : chr  "GALICIA" "ASTURIAS" "GALICIA" "ASTURIAS" ...
 $ provincia    : chr  "PONTEVEDRA" "ASTURIAS" "PONTEVEDRA" "ASTURIAS" ...
 $ lon          : num  -8.41 -5.84 -8.73 -6.07 -8.31 ...
 $ lat          : num  42.1 43.1 42 43.4 42.1 ...
```

So again **I would like to overwrite 11 rows of the `geoIncendios` dataset with the ones from the `outliers` dataset. I believe I have to use some kind of loop.** But in case there is a easiest solution (which I doubt it), these are the IDs of the rows: 9,13,22,24,37,40,43,45,68,93 and 99.

Comment: Maybe you could try `geoIncendios[outliers$id,] <- outliers[1:11,]`.

Comment: Thanks mate. I have to come back to the basics... :^)

Answer (score 0):

In the data you've shown, `geoIncendios$id` is just the row number of the `data.frame`. Presuming that's true for the whole dataset, you could use (as suggested in comments by @RHertel)

```
geoIncendios[outliers$id, ] <- outliers
```

However, if there are discontinuities in your id column, or if the order isn't strictly the same as the row numbers, a more generalisable solution is:

```
geoIncendios[match(outliers$id, geoIncendios$id), ] <- outliers
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for your answer. The data has not discontinuities, so the first option (as the one proposed by @RHertel) would serve (in fact, it did). But I will keep the other because it could be quite useful in the future.